# Named outlet not registered

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create a tabs component for one of my components, so I have used named outlet to handle this.

Currently, I have my default outlet that displays each page, and I would like to add a named outlet inside one of my component, problem is that it look like the named outlet is not registered to the OutletMap dynamically, which result in the error

```ts
Error: Cannot find the outlet tabs to load 'TabsDeaComponent'
```

I've tried a lot of things but I can't fix it, it just does not work.

app.component.html

```ts
<div class="menu">
  <h1>Menu de recherche</h1>

  <button (click)="search">Recherche</button>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

tabs-routing.module.ts

```ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'tabs', component: TabsComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'tabsdea', component: TabsDeaComponent, outlet: 'tabs' },
    { path: 'tabsiis', component: TabsIisComponent, outlet: 'tabs' },
    { path: 'tabsother', component: TabsOtherComponent, outlet: 'tabs' }
];
```

Tabs.component.ts

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { tabs: ['tabsdea'] } }]">Ouvrir la tab DEA</a>
<a [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { tabs: ['tabsiis'] } }]">Ouvrir la tab IIS</a>
<a [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { tabs: ['tabsother'] } }]">Ouvrir la tab Other</a>

<router-outlet name="tabs"></router-outlet>
```

As you can see, the named router-outlet is inside the default router-outlet, which, in my opinion, cause this issue of unregistered outlet.

Github repo to reproduce this issue: https://github.com/Sakuto/TabsPOC
Plunkr to reproduce this issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/P4q9yib0x9KtE15AQZAO?p=preview

**update**
Angular issue created https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14051

Comment: The question should contain the relevant code directly instead of just a link to some external resource.

Comment: Done, useful code is shown.

Answer (score 1):

How about change your App component to:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <router-outlet name="tabs"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Remember of remove  of your tabs template file, leave there only the links.